# Angular application not working in edge browser

Tags: angular

We developed an application in angular technology and first we hosted the application in test server and application was working fine in chrome, firefox and edge. Next same code was deployed in production server but application not opening in edge but working fine in chrome and firefox. In edge, we are not able to see anything in developer tools as well.

[image]

Comment: where is the details?

Comment: Image added in description

Comment: Do you have the correct url? What does the NETWORK tab say in the devolpment tools? There should be activity, if not something else is blocking your http request.

Comment: Application is hosted in internet server. Nothing is coming in network tab. But other applications are working fine in same server

Comment: "Nothing is coming in network tab" <- you should always have at least 1 record for the initial request the browser makes to the URL in the url bar. You should see what is returned here and can then figure out what to do next based on that response.

Comment: @Gunasekaran - STRONG SUGGESTION: Look here https://textslashplain.com/2020/01/17/capture-network-logs-from-edge-and-chrome/ and here: https://textslashplain.com/2022/01/20/debugging-compatibility-in-edge/.